# Best way to make loop range conditional?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to understand what would be the most efficient way to limit the range of my loop. The idea here is that my j is inputted into a function which needs to have i determined beforehand.

One of the constraints of the problem I am dealing with, is that j must always be less than i.

```
max_value = None

for i in range(1,1499):
    for j in range(1,1499):
        if i > j:
            candidate = some_function(i,j)
            if candidate > max_value:
                max_value = candidate
```

Now my i > j statement is not necessary here, because the best solution is always going to be one where i > j. However, because I know this, I want to leverage this in constraining my range, and stop the program from calculating more loops than necessary.

What is the best way to go about this? I was thinking something along the lines of this might work:

```
max_value = None

for i in range(1,1499):
    for j in range(1,i):
        candidate = some_function(i,j)
        if candidate > max_value:
            max_value = candidate
```

Any other ideas, or suggestions? The actual looping problem is much larger than this, so speed is a consideration, and any advice is more than welcome!

Comment: "might work"? have you tried it?

Comment: It will work after you fix your indentation (you have no colon at the end of your "if" line, and the next line should be indented). Also, if you're using Python < 3, using `xrange()` should speed it up as well.

Comment: Besides all the above comments, which are relevant, just try. `timeit` should do it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Yes this is correct, I made the mistake when simplifying the code for posting here, but as Lee pointed out, those corrections are what it would take for the code to run. And yes BartoszKP I have tried it, excuse the wrong word choice with "might". I am simply checking if there are other/better ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest way to write this in python would likely be:

```
max(some_function(i,j) for i in xrange(1, 1499) for j in xrange(1, i))
```

Now you don't create the unnecessary lists with `range`, and most execution will be in C code because it's just a generator expression not explicit python looping.

Of course, check your results with `timeit` as the commentators have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks wim. is there any reason why one would ever use xrange instead of range in a for loop? Searching online, I have gathered that in a for loop, it is the same thing, but simply more efficient for iterating and therefore faster.

Comment: I'd suggest using `for j, i in itertools.combinations(xrange(1, 1499), 2)` rather than two `for` clauses in your generator expression.

Comment: use `xrange` if you don't need the generated list for anything (other than iterating).  use `range` if you want the list, e.g. for indexing.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght ... but why do you prefer it?  The performance difference is small and it is not immediately obvious to me that the invariant `i > j` is satisfied with that form (it does seem to be equivalent, because combinations produces tuples in sorted order, but I had to manually check..)

Comment: @wim: Well, for one thing, you only need to call `xrange` once, rather than 1500 times. I guess it doesn't quite generate the same sequence of 2-tuples. It'll have all the same values, just in a different order (`(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), ...` rather than `(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,4), (2,4), ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Cool things can be done by using `i` in `range`. That is,:

```
for i in range(1,1499):
    for j in range(1,i):
        candidate = some_function(i,j)
        if candidate > max_value:
            max_value = candidate
```

Also note that I fixed an indentation at `max_value = candidate`.